# How can I change an int to a String for this object?

Tags: java, casting

I'm learning Java here, and using a "GLabel" object.  It's in the ACM Graphics library, and you can read about it here:

http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GLabel.html

In short, the GLabel prints a string.  The thing is I have an int that I want to print there.  How would I achieve this?

This is the loop I have, but this won't compile because of the int there.

```
for( int k = 1; i> 5; k++){
    GLabel counter = new GLabel(k);
    add(counter, (getWidth() / 2), (getHeight() / 2) );
    pause (500);
    remove(counter);
}
```

When I try this: `GLabel( (String)k);` I get a "Cannot cast from int to String" error...

EDIT: I have seen the setLabel method-maybe that is the only way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `GLabel("" + k);` instead.

You can't cast an `int` to a `String`, so you have to do a conversion instead. There are various ways to do this, but an easy way is to just append it to an empty string.

Other ways:

- [`String.valueOf(k)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29)
- [`Integer.toString(k)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29)
- [`String.format("%d", k)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

One caveat with using the `+` string concatenation "trick" is that you need to take operator precedence into account.

```
System.out.println("" + 1 + 2);   // this prints "12"
System.out.println("" + (1 + 2)); // this prints "3"
```

Comment: That worked!  I had tried GLabel( + k +); with no success but hadn't thought about that.  Thanks!

Comment: Using `("" + k)` => horrible! `String.valueOf(k)` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

`Integer.toString(k)`